# How to change values in ComboBox 2 when values of ComboBox 1 gets change (Values of both combobox are in SQL Database)

Tags: c#, sql, database, combobox, windows-forms-designer

As title suggests, I want to show the values of `comboBox2` when values are in `comboBox1` get change.

For.Eg: We have mealtypes in `comboBox1` (burger,cold drink, biryani) and we want to show Values in `comboBox2` like when someone selects Burger from `comboBox1` then there should be Chicken Burger,Beef Burger, Zinger Burger in ComboBox 2 which we have mentioned in database in Meals table and we have also made a table of Meal Types in database (Meal Types will be in `comboBox1` and Meals will be in `comboBox2` in Visual Studio Form).

```
public partial class ordermeal: Form {
    public ordermeal() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    Meal_Delivery_Management_System md = new Meal_Delivery_Management_System();

    private void ordermeal_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {

        comboBox1.DataSource = md.GetALLMealTypes();
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "typename";
        comboBox1.ValueMember = "mealtypeid";

        comboBox2.DataSource = md.GetMeals();
        comboBox2.DisplayMember = "Mealname";
        comboBox2.ValueMember = "unitprice";



    }

    private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a bit more information here? Specifically about what GUI you're using. Are you using .Net? A web page? Because what you're asking is not about database access ... it's about user interface stuff. Oops, you've edited. So you're working with C#. It might be worth tagging the question with "C#".

Comment: Now if you got my query then please reply, Waiting..

Comment: I'm probably not the best person to answer. I'd suggest you add a "changed" event handler for comboBox1. When that gets triggered, look at the value in the combo, and make a query on the database, looking for the meals that correspond to the meal type. Then clear out and repopulate comboBox2. But there are probably more efficient ways of doing this by associating data sets with the controls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make two methods for your Combobox and call your mealtype combobox in constroctor 
here is sample

```
     public ordermeal() 
     {
        InitializeComponent();
        yourMealtypeCombobox();
     }


       public void yourMealtypeCombobox()
        {
            DataTable dt = md.GetALLMealTypes(); // 
            comboBox1.DataSource = dt;
            comboBox1.DisplayMember = "typename";
            comboBox1.ValueMember = "mealtypeid";
        }



    public void yourMealCombo(int mealtypeid)
            {
                DataTable dt = md.GetMeals(mealtypeid); // Get your corresponding meal by mealtypeid of Selected mealtype by users
/* i am assuming your GetMeals() method is able to except input parameter and filter records from input parameter */
                comboBox2.DataSource = dt;
                comboBox2.DisplayMember = "Mealname";
                comboBox2.ValueMember = "unitprice";

            }
```

and call combobox selection changedcommited event of both combobox1

```
    private void comboBox1_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      // here Get the Selected Type of of meal
      int mealTypeId = Convert.ToInt32(comboBox1.SelectedValue);// here i am not checking null but you should do it
     // finaly call mealcombo from here
     yourMealCombo(mealTypeId);
    }
```